# IOUtils.ToByteArray(InputStream) is thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, ioutils

Can using `IOUtils.ToByteArray` leads to concurrency problems?

```
private byte[] saveLetterContent(InputStream input) {
  ...

  byte[] letterContent = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);

  ...
}
```

I mean is it possible that `letterContent` in this method change incorrectly because of concurrency?

Comment: Even if you take measures to make the code thread-safe the result would be that one byte array contains the stream's contents and any other byte array would be empty, because the first thread to consume the stream has, well, consumed the stream.

Comment: Do you try to call saveLetterContent for the same instance on InputStream in more than one single thread? I really doubt :)... But if so, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

> I mean is it possible that letterContent in this method change
> incorrectly because of concurrency?

Absolutely, calling `toByteArray(InputStream)` without *guarding* the inputted `InputStream` can lead to undefined behavior. It is also easily demonstrable.

```
final String value = "hello! ciao!";
final byte[] valueBytes = value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(valueBytes.length);

final ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(valueBytes);

new Thread(() -> {
   try {
      is.read(new byte[10]);
   } catch (final IOException e) {
      //
   }
}).start();

// Thread.sleep(50)

final byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
System.out.println(bytes.length);
```

With the above example, you'll surely notice the second `System.out` will print a lower bytes length than the first one. You can even play with `Thread.sleep` and see what happens.

[image]

Comment: what is the best alternative for toByteArray in multithread application?

Comment: @elahe none, you have to synchronize usage of the InputStream by yourself.

Comment: I think in your code the order of threads does not Guarantee the order of outputs

Comment: @elahe my code does not synchronize on purpose

Comment: @elahe you need to wrap usages with Locks or synchronized blocks